# Getting specific rows according to a subset in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I've been trying for hours with this one. I have a dataset with two columns, let's call them V1 and V2.I also have a list of imporatant V1 values - Vx. I managed to acquire a subset of V1 with intersect function, so:

```
intersect <- intersect(df$V1,Vx)
```

Now I am desperately trying to get V2 values, corresponding to this subset.
I've tried with

```
subset <- df[intersect(df$V1,Vx),]
```

But it returns me values, which are all NAs.
So to explain with another case:
I have a dataset

```
V1      V2
a54    hi
bc85   hk
sdx637 hi
vbd435 hk
```

And also a list, containing

```
l <- c("a54","sdx637")
```

What I am trying to get is:

```
 V1      V2
 a54    hi
 sdx637 hi
```

As I said, the code I've been using gives me all NAs, are there any alternatives? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
subset(df, V1 %in% l)
#      V1 V2
#1    a54 hi
#3 sdx637 hi
```

`intersect` can be used to get the common elements

```
 intersect(df$V1, l)
 #[1] "a54"    "sdx637"
```

but this will not give a logical index to subset the data,

```
 df[intersect(df$V1, l),]
 #     V1   V2
 #NA   <NA> <NA>
 #NA.1 <NA> <NA>
```

But `%in%` returns a logical index, which will be useful for subsetting.

As @Steven Beaupré mentioned in the comments, other options include `[` or `filter` from `dplyr`

```
  df[df$V1 %in% l,]
```

Or

```
  library(dplyr)
  filter(df, V1 %in% l)
```

Or

```
  library(data.table)
  setDT(df)[V1 %chin% l]
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. There is one other thing though. What do you think can be the reason behind the fact that my l is let's say 300 element long, but the resulting subset is longer? Are there duplicates?

Comment: @sdgawerzswer  There would be duplicates for that column.  You can check  `any(table(df$V1)>1)`
to see if there are more than one element